# What should I check for my old cat?

Tags: cats, health

My cat is a 12-years old American short-hair male.
I think I have to take him to a vet for a medical check-up because he is quite old.

The inspection items may vary by a vet, so I wonder what are 'must-do' items for a health examination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need is to get a full set of bloodwork done, this is to find changes in kidney function, to measure glucose levels to see if your cat has diabetes or any other problems you can see on blood tests.

In most cats, you will find weakened kidneys at the age of about 10 years+; the earlier you get kidney problems diagnosed and treated the longer your cat will live.

Next, you will need to get the urine tested for crystals and the poop tested for parasites; parasites can shorten your cat's life if left untreated.

Lastly, you might want an ultrasound of your cat's hips and joints; most older cats will get pain in their joints as they get older.

The blood samples are the most important to get the answers, the road ahead depends on the findings if any.

So bloodwork is the most important to get done and it is where you get the most information about your cat for the money.

Urine and stool samples should be done.

Ultrasound is mostly to confirm other findings so it is something you can get done at a later time.

The tests and samples are in addition to the regular checkup by your vet.